# navigate back after handling intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an application. I want it to appear when I tap "share" in other applications. Then I want it to process the data it has received and go back to the caller application.

E.g. I am sharing a facebook post:
1) My app opens
2) Saves info to DB
3) Returns to FB post

How can this return to FB post be achieved?

I tried referring to `callingActivity`, but it is null.

Intent filter:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val intent = intent
    val action = intent.action
    val type = intent.type


    if (intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) != null) {

        // do some processing

        // goes recursively
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your current code so we can see how far you've gotten? Are you getting the data in your app but failing to process or is the data never getting to your app?

Comment: @SRoseDev88, I have updated the question, but I don't have much 
Problem is that I have to open FB app again, after processing data

Answer (score 0):

Whatever app you shared from will be active behind your current application so you will be able to share to your app and then just stop your app using `finish()`. I did a quick test and was able to share from a couple of apps using this approach. Your app will flash up then the user will land back in the app they shared from after your database write is complete. I logged the intent to make sure it was coming through properly and was able to see links from chrome (as an example).

```
 if (intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT) != null) {

        // do some processing
        Log.d("Extras", intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT))

        // goes recursively
        finish()
    }
```

Comment: And if the processing takes a long time? Is there any way to launch it in the background? Or to just minimize my app, so that calling app was showed

Comment: You could turn your process into a service, which would allow it to run in the background. Your in-app code could parse the data then pass it to the service. After the data is passed you could close your application and allow the service to do the work in the background.